# How do I sync Evolution's "Sent" folder?

Tags: ubuntu-one, evolution

Is there any way to sync the *Sent* folder in Evolution in Ubuntu One? Received items are updated from the mail server as I leave them there 7 days before deletion, but I need to keep my sent items on each computer too.

Comment: Are you using IMAP or POP?

Answer (score 1):

Evolution by default stores the send mails for every account you create on a local folder to your computer. This folder can be accessed either by the evolution interface ("On this computer --> Sent") or by navigating to `/home/YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/.evolution/mail/local` and locating the file named "**Sent**". (This file is actually a [.mbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) file and you can even open it with gedit!)

So to sync this file with Ubuntu One just add a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) script to copy that .mbox file to your Ubuntu One folder. I give you an example of running the copy process every 5 minutes:

```
$gksu gedit /etc/crontab
```

add at the end of that file :

```
*/5 * * * *  YOUR_USERNAME_HERE  cp /home/YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/.evolution/mail/local/Sent /home/YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/Ubuntu\ One/
```

replaces YOUR_USERNAME_HERE in the command above.